# Generating keystore but only getting SHA1 certificate, I want SHA256 certificate?

Tags: java, android, sdk, keystore, keytool

I'm not an expert at these but I'm just following the code as listed on the Android developers website

keytool -genkey -v -keystore orbii.jks
-keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias orbii

for signing a keystore. However, I end up getting a SHA1 certificate for the keytool? I have the latest version of Android SDK and I need a SHA256 certificate in order to be able to use the Amazon Gamecircle feature. How can I create a keystore with a SHA256 certificate instead of SHA1? Thanks!

Comment: See this answer for full keytool arguments(rsa, sha256, SubAltName, etc..) also use Java7 or Java8 https://stackoverflow.com/a/61674251/185565

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using Java 6.

Keytool from JDK 7 and higher uses **SHA256WithRSA** for **RSA** and **SHA256withECDSA** for **EC** key pairs as default algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Specify `-sigalg SHA256withRSA`. Strange its not defaulting to this however, as Java `6` and `7` both should.